# Error while trying to view random value of weight and bias

Tags: python, pytorch

```
from torch import nn


class LinearRegressionModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weights=nn.parameter(torch.randn(1,requires_gradient=True,dtype=torch.float))
        self.bias=nn.parameter(torch.randn(1,requires_gradient=True,dtype=torch.float))   

    def forward(self,X:torch.tensor)->torch.tensor:
        return self.weights*X+self.bias


torch.manual_seed(32)
model_0=LinearRegressionModel()
model_0
```

These three lines of code gives an error like this
How can I correct the code?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e7c14f2c2a90> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 torch.manual_seed(32)
----> 2 model_0=LinearRegressionModel()
      3 model_0
<ipython-input-23-44002508539b> in __init__(self)
      3     def __init__(self):
      4         super().__init__()
----> 5         self.weights=nn.parameter(torch.randn(1,requires_gradient=True,dtype=torch.float))
      6         self.bias=nn.parameter(torch.randn(1,requires_gradient=True,dtype=torch.float))
      7     def forward(self,X:torch.tensor)->torch.tensor:

TypeError: randn() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (int, dtype=torch.dtype, requires_gradient=bool), but expected one of:

 * (tuple of ints size, *, torch.Generator generator, tuple of names names, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (tuple of ints size, *, torch.Generator generator, Tensor out, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (tuple of ints size, *, Tensor out, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (tuple of ints size, *, tuple of names names, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
```

Initially I tried to print the random weight and bias through `module_0.parameters()` but gave error as `LinearRegressionModel()` not defined so I tried to only see what module_0 returns at first but it gave the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the torch.randn [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randn.html) your keyword args are slightly off (You can see this in the error message, as it tells you it got incorrect arguments). It should be `requires_grad=True` rather than `requires_gradient=True`. Also, be sure that you're creating a [`nn.parameter.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html) rather than `nn.parameter`, as `nn.parameter` is the name of the module, not the class.